# Adding rivets to plane

Tags: add-on

New to blender. learning as I go along. Here's what I need help with adding rivets to this plane but I am going at it at eye level. I want to know how I can add a pattern of rivets to the plane and have the rivets the same size as the rivets on a different model.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select a rivet of your other object, duplicate it, separate to make a new object (<kbd>P</kbd>), make sure that the origin is at the bottom of the object (or slightly higher) because it will be the origin that will snap to the surface, enable the *Snap* option with *Face Project* and *Align Rotation to Target* enabled:

[image]

Move you rivet, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in order to snap to the surface of your new object, link-duplicate the rivet with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and so on:

[image]

You can them change the shape of the rivet, or join them to the object with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.